# connect with email OR phone number with devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, devise

I'm looking to allow users to connect to their account with their email **or** their phone number. I have checked that we can change authentication_keys on devise settings, but it's an "**and**" method instead of an "**or**".

Any idea?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Please refer to the below article for details

[How To: Allow users to sign in using their username or email address](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To%3a-Allow-users-to-sign-in-using-their-username-or-email-address)

You can simulate your application in the similar way on `phone number` or `email`.
I just saved myself from repeating the whole process from article.